# Synchronize SourceSafe with SVN

Tags: svn, version-control, synchronization, visual-sourcesafe

Our company has a policy imposing the requirement of keeping source code in a SourceSafe repository. I've tried hard to persuade the management to migrate to SVN with no success (whcih is an another issue, anyway).

As I and few of my colleagues use SVN repository placed on my computer (via Apache), I made a PowerShell script which does backups of the repository onto a company server (which is then periodically backed up as well). This works well, but say I wanted also to keep a copy of the source code on our SourceSafe server.

Any experience or tips on doing that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a **good** way, but one way would be to use [SVN Server Hooks](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks) to perform similar actions in Source Safe using the VSS command-line tools.  I think this has been discussed before on the svn-user's mailing list.  You could try searching the [archives here](http://svn.haxx.se/).

Answer (score 3):

How about checking in the ***SVN Repository*** to SourceSafe?

Comment: +1 Brutal, but if a company is going to insist on using VisualSourceDestruct, then it will serve them right to find the letter of their law adhered to in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Poor you, I feel your pain.

How about a nightly export of your code zipped up and stored in VSS?  Most tools are for moving the other way so if you want this automated you will have to write something yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a good idea to create a batch file that regularly checks the current sourcecode from SVN into sourcesafe.

You could create a batch file that is run every night via a scheduled task.  It would use [sourcesafe command line utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asxkfzy4(VS.80).aspx) to check out the entire codebase to the local filesystem.  It would then do the same thing using the [subversion command line client](https://www.projects.dev2dev.bea.com/Subversion%20Clients/CommandLineSVN.html) to do a get on the latest version into the same directory.  You can then check in using the sourcesafe command line util.

The hard part would be detecting new files added to subversion and adding those to the sourcesafe database.  You could, hypothetically, iterate through all the files and see which ones aren't marked readonly after the last checkin.  Another issue would be handling renames and deletes; I suppose it wouldn't much matter that deleted files remain in sourcesafe, since it sounds like nobody is actually using that codebase.